# VBA shows error in filtering cells on first run but nor second

Tags: excel, vba

When I run the code below for the first time I get the following error.  The code just filters everything out except the cells in red.

[image]

When I go back into the sheet and click on an empty cell and the rerun the code, it works prefect.  Not sure whats going on here

```
Option Explicit
Sub FilterColorToRed()
'
' FilterColorToRed Macro
'

'
    Range("A1").Select
    
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$G$634").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 0 _
        , 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor



End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: how does the sheet you are filtering get created?

Comment: It basicall gets created by VBA comparing cells in two different sheets and placing them on this sheet and coloring the cells that don't match as red, those that do as blue.

Comment: is there actually any data on the new sheet when the filter is ran?  If it is empty this error is raised.

Comment: Yes, I have added a picture in the question as what data is in the sheet

Comment: add a **debug.print activesheet.name** to the filter sub as the first line, and look at the immediate window to see what sheet is **active**.

Comment: Thanks.  That was the problem.  I had it from the workbook instead of the specific sheet